# Work Done by an Adiabatic Expansion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas, adiabatic

I am given the information that a parcel of air expands adiabatically (no exchange of heat between parcel and its surroundings) to five times its original volume, and its initial temperature is 20° C. Using this information, how can I determine the amount of work done by the parcel on its surroundings?

I know that $dq = 0$, and that $du + dW = dq = 0$, but I don't know what to do with this information. $dW = pdV$, which seems like it should be helpful, but I don't know what to do for the pressure.

Comment: I just wanted to comment because some people are bound to think this violates our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) - but personally I think you just make it into the domain of acceptable homework-like questions because you narrowed the problem down to the underlying concept, which is that you don't see a way to get the pressure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More clues? :-)

This is harder then the isobaric process because now the pressure is a function of volume. You need to write the pressure as a function of volume, then integrate it from the initial to final volume. For some clues see the Wikipedia article on [adiabatic expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_process#Ideal_gas_.28reversible_process.29). Although the question doesn't say so, you'll need to assume the expansion is reversible as the question can't be answered otherwise.

Comment: If I use $pV = RT$, then $p = \frac{RT}{V}$. Using $\delta w = pdV$, then $w = RT \int{\frac{1}{V}} dV$. Solving this gives me $w = RT\ln(5)$, which, after plugging numbers in, gives me $w = (287)(293)\ln5 = 1.35339 * 10^5$. And I was just sent an email saying that the book's answer is wrong and this one is correct. Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it (and I do completely get it now)!

Comment: Hmm, actually that's wrong. The temperature is a function of volume as well, so you can't just assume the pressure is constant. The way to do it is to note that for a reversible adiabatic expansion $PV^\gamma$ is a constant, where $\gamma$ is a constant related to the type of gas.

Answer (score 1):

$PV^\gamma=\rm constant$ for adiabats,so use 
$$
W=\int\frac{\rm const}{V^γ} dV
$$
then recall that the constant in the integration is $PV^\gamma$. You should get 
$$
\frac{1}{(1-\gamma)}(PV)
$$
evaluated between the two volumes and pressures.

Answer (score 0):

dq=0 in an adiabatic reversible process.
From First Law of Thermodynamics,

dE = dq + dW  (But dq=0)

Therefore dE = dW.
 It implies that

nC<sub>v</sub>dT = -Pdv

C<sub>v</sub> = (-RT/V)dv

C<sub>v</sub>(dt)/T = -Rdv/V

On integrating with limits T<sub>1</sub>,T<sub>2</sub> and V<sub>1</sub>,V<sub>2</sub>,

(T<sub>2</sub>/T<sub>1</sub>)<sup>C<sub>v</sub>/R</sup> = V<sub>1</sub>/V<sub>2</sub>.

( I will post the rest of the answer later ..........)

Comment: Please format your equations using MathJax syntax